# How can I dynamically build a View for SwiftUI and present it?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I've included stubbed code samples. I'm not sure how to get this presentation to work. My expectation is that when the sheet presentation closure is evaluated, `aDependency` should be non-nil. However, what is happening is that `aDependency` is being treated as nil, and `TheNextView` never gets put on screen.

How can I model this such that `TheNextView` is shown? What am I missing here?

```
struct ADependency {}

struct AModel {
    func buildDependencyForNextExperience() -> ADependency? {
        return ADependency()
    }
}

struct ATestView_PresentationOccursButNextViewNotShown: View {
    @State private var aDependency: ADependency?
    @State private var isPresenting = false
    @State private var wantsPresent = false {
        didSet {
            aDependency = model.buildDependencyForNextExperience()
            isPresenting = true
        }
    }
    private let model = AModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Tap to present")
            .onTapGesture {
                wantsPresent = true
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresenting, content: {
                if let dependency = aDependency {
                    // Never executed
                    TheNextView(aDependency: dependency)
                }
            })
    }
}

struct TheNextView: View {
    let aDependency: ADependency
    
    init(aDependency: ADependency) {
        self.aDependency = aDependency
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Next Screen")
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to initialise aDependency on state change? Is that a required condition?

Comment: @TusharSharma correct! Yes

Comment: why not do it in initialiser? When you tap on text, you can just toggle isPresented to true, and sheet will be invoked. As you already initialised dependency while initialisation it won’t be nil? Isn’t that what you want?

Comment: @TusharSharma the dependency isn’t computer at compile time and is computed after the user clicks on a button

Comment: what about doing-: "TheNextView(aDependency:model.buildDependencyForNextExperience())”. Model is providing object, so why not pass it directly when presentation sheet? You can also remove wantsPresent and adependency state properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem in iOS 14. The `sheet(isPresented:)` gets evaluated on first render and then does not correctly update.

To get around this, you can use `sheet(item:)`. The only catch is your item has to conform to `Identifiable`.

The following version of your code works:

```
struct ADependency : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
}

struct AModel {
    func buildDependencyForNextExperience() -> ADependency? {
        return ADependency()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var aDependency: ADependency?
    private let model = AModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Tap to present")
            .onTapGesture {
                aDependency = model.buildDependencyForNextExperience()
            }
            .sheet(item: $aDependency, content: { (item) in
                TheNextView(aDependency: item)
            })
    }
}
```